# How to bind the input data enter with span text?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new in Vue.js. I'm trying to bind the data of the input field with the to the span data but it will not appending it tells me `undefined`

Code:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    name: "hello"
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function(step, $event) {
      this.counter += step
    },
    decrement: function(step, $event) {
      this.counter -= step
    },
    points: function(event) {
      this.x = event.clientX;
      this.y = event.clientY;
    },
    alert: function(event) {
      alert("alert!")
    },
    change: function(value) {
      this.name = this.name + value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="change(value)" value="">
  <span>{{name}}</span>
</div>
```

Why this will showing me error when I will press enter key but it will append `undefined` on every enter press. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

your argument to your `change` method is wrong. Use this one:

`<input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="change($event.target.value)">`.

You can get more information regarding this in [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#example-3).

Answer (score 0):

If am understanding it correctly, you want to reflect the input value in the span tag. So you got to bind the `name` value to the `input` the same way you have bound it to span tag using `v-model`, else everything else you did is right.

`<input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="change(value)" v-model="name" />`

Now once you have done the above, your code will work to reflect any changes to the text box inside of the span tag.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    name: "hello"
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function(step, $event) {
      this.counter += step
    },
    decrement: function(step, $event) {
      this.counter -= step
    },
    points: function(event) {
      this.x = event.clientX;
      this.y = event.clientY;
    },
    alert: function(event) {
      alert("alert!")
    },
    change: function(value) {
      this.name = this.name + value
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-on:keyup.enter="change(value)" v-model="name" />
  <span>{{name}}</span>
</div>
```